# django jquery $.get to $.post

Tags: jquery, django, post, get

in django I have

```
#template
$.get("/places/{{ place.id }}/save/",{description : cadena }

#view
place.description = request.POST.getlist('description')[0]
```

work ok.
but If try change to `$.post`

```
#template
$.post("/places/{{ place.id }}/save/",{description : cadena }

#view
print request.POST
```

nothing happend

## solved

my problem, I don't added `context_instance=RequestContext(request)` in the view of send the `$.post` for this `crsf_token` don't exist.

with this change now work

```
 $.post("/places/{{ place.id }}/save/",{description : cadena, csrfmiddlewaretoken: '{{ csrf_token }}'}
```

and is necessary  `{{ csrf_token }}` not `{% csrf_token %}`.
`{% csrf_token %}` create a `<input ...>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're probably running into a Cross Site Request Forgery (CSRF) problem - Django is rejecting the POST because there's no CSRF token. For Ajax, you will need to do some special handling, or mark the view as `csrf_exempt`. More information about this can be found here:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/csrf/#ajax

Comment: in your template could try: $.post("/places/{{ place.id }}/save/",{description : cadena, csrfmiddlewaretoken: '{{ csrf_token }}'}, this applies for Django 1.3, versions before use csrftoken instead of csrfmiddlewaretoken i think

Comment: @Jingo I changed to `{description : cadena, csrfmiddlewaretoken: '{{ csrf_token }}'}` , but nothing happend

Comment: I think it's `{% csrf_token %}` (note: `{%` not `{{`)

Comment: @Dan-breen , with I get `<QueryDict: {u'csrfmiddlewaretoken': [u''], u'description': [u'test text']}>`

Comment: what Django version are you using? And have you already tried Dan´s suggestion, try to exempt your view from csrf protection and see whether it works.

Comment: @DanBreen if I put `{% csrf_token %}` I get a warning `... A {% csrf_token %} was used in a template, but the context did not provide the value...`