# Jquery $post request is not working in Django

Tags: jquery, django, post, get

I am trying to use the $post request from javascript into my django template, but there is something I am missing, since it is not working.

I will show you my code:

This is the template:

```
//TEMPLATE
//This code will send a string to django "views.py" file,
//then it will show a pop up message from the data retreived from "views.py"

function test_post(){ 
   $.post("/xhr_test", 
      {name: "Monty", food: "Spam", csrftoken : "{{ csrf_token }}" },

      function(data) {
          alert(data)
      ;}); 
};
```

This is the views.py:

```
// VIEWS.PY
//Depending on the type of request it will send a message or another.


def xhr_test(request):
    if request.is_ajax():
        if request.method == 'GET':
            message = "This is an XHR GET request"
        elif request.method == 'POST':
            message = "This is an XHR POST request"
            # Here we can access the POST data
            print request.POST
    else:
        message = "No XHR"
    return HttpResponse(message)
```

This code does not show the "This is an XHR POST request" message as it should. However it does show the "This is an XHR GET request" message when using the $get request.

A similar doubt was answer in this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9085068/django-jquery-get-to-post). Even though I am using the answers that were provided there, the code does not work.

I am guessing the answer must be related to the "{{ csrf_token }}", but not sure how...

Any type of help will be appreciated.

Comment: how do you populate `csrf_token`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this is due to csrf token (you can check it in your browser using firebug), then use this in your views.py

```
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt

@csrf_exempt
def xhr_test(request):
   ...........
```

Comment: Why would you like to disable csrf protection?

Comment: whenever we are using ajax or jquery in our templates we generally got the error of csrf token even if we are using middleware so its the one way of checking weather there is another error or just the csrf missing error.I am not forcing anyone to use this but just for testing purpose.

Comment: Obviously Inforian told me to use the "csrf_exempt" for debuging purposes. I have never heared about firedebug, and it is really helpful.

It worked with the @csrf_exempt. However, not without it. I am going to read carefully the advices that firedbug told me, and I will let you know.

Answer (score 0):

The correct post key for csrf token is `csrfmiddlewaretoken` if you're following the default way of using `django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware`.

However you should look at the AJAX section in CSRF [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/csrf/#ajax).