# CSRF error when using $post in django

Tags: jquery, django, post, csrf

I posted recently a similar question. I have a problem using the $post jquery form in my django app. It shows a 403 error.

In my [previous thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14334901/jquery-post-request-is-not-working-in-django), with the answers provided, I narrowed down the possible errors and helped me find a [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5100539/django-csrf-check-failing-with-an-ajax-post-request) with a similar question.

The author of that thread had the same problem as I do. However, the most voted answer doesn't work for me. Instead the one that does is this one:

```
//Everything works if I add the 
//"csrfmiddlewaretoken: '{{ csrf_token }}'"
//in the data sent to the server.

function test_post(){ 
  $.post("/xhr_test/", {
      name: "Monty",
      food: "Spam",
      csrfmiddlewaretoken: '{{ csrf_token }}'
  },
      function(data) {
          alert(data);
      }

  ); 
};
```

Although it works, I don't like this solution, since I have to add that "csrfmiddlewaretoken" to all the strings I send.

I want to understand why the most voted solution doesn't work for me since I considered it to be a more elegant one. That is, adding these lines of code:

```
$.ajaxSetup({ 
     beforeSend: function(xhr, settings) {
         function getCookie(name) {
             var cookieValue = null;
             if (document.cookie && document.cookie != '') {
                 var cookies = document.cookie.split(';');
                 for (var i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
                     var cookie = jQuery.trim(cookies[i]);
                     // Does this cookie string begin with the name we want?
                 if (cookie.substring(0, name.length + 1) == (name + '=')) {
                     cookieValue = decodeURIComponent(cookie.substring(name.length + 1));
                     break;
                 }
             }
         }
         return cookieValue;
         }
         if (!(/^http:.*/.test(settings.url) || /^https:.*/.test(settings.url))) {
             // Only send the token to relative URLs i.e. locally.
             xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", getCookie('csrftoken'));
         }
     } 
});
```

I think it has to be something with the "(!(/^http:.*/.test(settings.url)" part. Might have to change something there, but not sure what.

Comment: what's your jquery version?

Answer (score 0):

First, make sure your cookies are enabled, this is because in this method, the csrftoken is taken from the cookie value, not from the templates.

Then, try pasting the code for the get_cookie function in the Chrome dev console, and then try getCookie('csrftoken').

If it returns with a csrftoken, the cookie is there.

Next, you need to make sure that the code for ajaxSetup is being called there. Put a `debugger` statement before the line like this:

```
 debugger 
 if (!(/^http:.*/.test(settings.url) || /^https:.*/.test(settings.url))) {
```

and step through the code to see if it sets the header properly.

It might be a good idea to try the one in the official docs.